# difference between addEventListener in js file and in script tag inside html page

Tags: javascript

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Understanding File upload and File access Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "files" name = "files[]" multiple></input>
    <output id = "list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt){
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a',') - ',
                    f.size, 'bytes, last modified: ',
                    f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                     '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

This example works perfectly and no errors. I get a error **TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null** if I call the javascript function from a js file. This code is below.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Understanding File upload and File access Javascript</title>
    <script src = "fileaccess.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "files" name = "files[]" multiple></input>
    <output id = "list"></output>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function handleFileSelect(evt){
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a',') - ',
                    f.size, 'bytes, last modified: ',
                    f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                     '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Now, what is the difference these both examples. I dont understand why I'm getting error if I'm calling the javascript function in a html page.

Comment: It's because your script file is included in the head, before the elements are available in the DOM. Place the script tag at the bottom, right before `</body>` instead.

Comment: K, let me check with that, a moment please.

Comment: Thank you so much, @adeneo. I just now understood why it was screaming till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the placement of the script.
In the first example the script tag is **after** the elements in the DOM, and in the second example the script tag is in the head, **before** the elements in the DOM.

To be able to get an element with `.getElementById` and any other such method, the element ***must first be loaded***, meaning the script must come after the element in the DOM, or the script needs to use an event handler to wait for the page to be loaded, such as `window.onload`, `DOMContentLoaded` etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Understanding File upload and File access Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "file" id = "files" name = "files[]" multiple></input>
    <output id = "list"></output>
    <script src = "fileaccess.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was trying this because, I want to upload an image and image should be set as background-image for my html page. So if u got some ideas please tell me.

Comment: Head loads before the rest page. So you are trying to access an element that is not yet loaded. You need to insert all your code inside a body onload event.

Comment: If you want to wait for images to load, do `window.onload = function() { ..all code here.. }`

Comment: I must put this window.onload function once I select the image when I click the browse button,?